# how realize click event on directive?

Tags: angularjs

Please help fix the script.

i make simply directive:

```
angular.module('menus', [])
  .directive("epMenu", ['$timeout', '$state',
    function ($timeout, $state) {
      return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.goTo = function(link) {
            console.log('go to', link);
          };

          var navigationElem = angular.element("<div class='ep-menu-navigation'><li ng-click='scope.goTo('main')'>qwerty</li></div>");

          angular.element('body').append(navigationElem);
        },

        restrict: "EACM"
      }
    }]);
```

but it does not work. I need to when you press the button, start function goTo()

Now the console following error message:

> VM436 angular.js:12520 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state <- epMenuDirective

[live example](https://jsfiddle.net/pc1u72tb/4/)

Comment: have you resolved the syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$state` is a provider that is registered in the `ui.router` module, so you have to lay that dependency:

```
angular.module('menus', ["ui.router"])
```

Also, if you are building the template dynamically in the `link` function, you have to compile it so that angular can apply its actions to it:

```
.directive("epMenu", ['$timeout', '$state', '$compile',
    function ($timeout, $state, $compile) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.goTo = function(link) {
                    console.log('go to', link);
                };

                var navigationElem = angular.element("<div class='ep-menu-navigation'><li ng-click='goTo('main')'>qwerty</li></div>");

                $compile(navigationElem)(scope, function(cloned){
                    angular.element('body').append(cloned);
                });
            },
            restrict: "EACM"
        }
    }]);
```

You also had some other errors in your code:

- Missing the angular ui router script
- Using `scope.goTo` instead of just `goTo`
- Not escaping the quotes in the `goTo` function
- Using jqLite, you cannot use `angular.element('body')`, instead use the `$document` service

[Here is a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/pc1u72tb/6/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have `ui.router` injected as dependency to your module.

```
angular.module('menus',["ui.router"])
```

If you want to change the state when clicked on a link created by a directive, **create a controller for the directive.**

use the `$state.go` in the controller to redirect.

In my answer, I used a controller, which changes the `state` to `menu` when clicked on the link of directive.

Here is the code to achieve it,

```
(function() {

  angular.module('menus')

  directive('epMenu', function () {

    var controller = ['$scope','$state', function ($scope,$state) {

          $scope.goTo = function(link) {
            $state.go(link)
          };

      }],

      template = "<div class='ep-menu-navigation'><li ng-click='goTo('main')'>qwerty</li></div>";

      return {
          restrict: 'EA', //Default in 1.3+
          controller: controller,
          template: template
      };
  });

}());
```

Comment: @prozaek.prozaek, i hope you want to change the state when clicked on the directive element. pls check my answer once

Comment: @prozaek.prozaek, what happened? any issue with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The error inside your code is because it does not find dependency for `$state`. you have to add `angular.module('menus', ["ui.router"])` because `$state` is registered inside `ui-router`.also you have to add proper js for `ui-router`. You can bind click event inside link function.

```js
angular.module('menus', ["ui.router"]).directive("epMenu", ['$timeout', '$state',
  function($timeout, $state) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('button').bind('click', function() {
          console.log("click");
        });
      },
      restrict: "EACM"
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
angular.module('menus',
["ui.router"])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="menus">
  <ep-menu>
    this is normal text
    <button>
      Click Me
    </button>
  </ep-menu>
</div>
```